# Why is AVR instruction format so complex?

Tags: avr, instruction-set

While looking at the atmel 8-bit AVR instruction set ( http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0856.pdf ) I found the instruction format quite complex. A lot of instructions have different bit fields, where bits of operands/opcode are at different places in the instruction: why is that so? Isn't it more difficult for the decode unit to actually decode the opcode and operands with this format?

Comment: that is just how they chose to do things, it is actually pretty rare to have the bitfields nicely organized, mips and folks that mimic mips do that but a lot of other instruction sets even old cisc where you would think every gate counts, didnt.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Getting an 8-bit micro-controller to provide a robust ISA that maps well to a sane C environment was a challenge - one that paid off well. Have a look at the AVR GCC port - it's about as easy to use as a C toolchain for an embedded target gets.  *AVR couldn't afford generous, fixed 4 byte instruction with fixed fields like early RISC architecture.* I have to disagree with your premise.

Answer (score 0):

I think it largely may come from considerations of compatibility.
On some stage one instruction gets more powerful and the additional option is encoded in the bits that are free, so that the old instruction word still invokes the old behaviour.